# Prove that every connected graph whose vertices are all of even degree has no cut-vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I am trying to prove that every connected graph whose vertices are all of even degree has no cut-vertices.

Now, I am not very good with proofs but I was thinking about proving it by contradiction,

Let G be a connected graph whose vertices are all even. 
Assume G contains a cut vertex v.
Let H be one of the components created when deleting v.

I am not sure how to continue from here. I suppose I need to prove that H has an odd number of odd degrees?

Comment: What about two triangles sharing a vertex? I suspect you want to show there is no no cut-edge rather than no cut-vertex.

Comment: Thank you, I was supposed to prove OR disprove the statement but for some reason I assumed it was true. I get it now.